# css linter expecting RBRACE around rotate function

Tags: css

Running the following chunk of CSS through [this linter](http://csslint.net)

```
.spin-out.mui-leave.mui-leave-active {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0.75turn);
      -ms-transform: rotate(0.75turn);
          transform: rotate(0.75turn);
  opacity: 0; }
```

and it is returning

```
Expected RBRACE at line 2, col 29.

  -webkit-transform: rotate(0.75turn);
```

this error crops up for every invocation of `rotate` of a much longer file.  The semi-colons appear appropriate and I do not believe the rotate function required curly brackets.

What could be going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The linter fail because csslint does not know the unit `turn`. You can make it pass with `deg`:

```
.spin-out.mui-leave.mui-leave-active {
      -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg);
          -ms-transform: rotate(270deg);
              transform: rotate(270deg);
      opacity: 0;
}
```

Note that like `deg`, `grad` and `rad`, `turn` should be [valid](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-values-3/#ref-for-turn) and [well supported](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/angle). I guess csslint is a bit old or buggy.

I found on GitHub an issue about `turn` and `csslint` from [2018](https://github.com/CSSLint/csslint/issues/732). The last release on GitHub was in 2016.

Time to switch to [Prettier](https://prettier.io/) maybe?

Comment: Very useful pointer to the history. The definition of variables for `:root` also generates misleads. Prettier is a swiss-knife; however the error messages of csslint are more *edifiants* (to this user).